# Execute FTP command file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

As described in the title, I want to login in the `ftp` server and run a local FTP command file with `ftp` commands, in one single command that will be executed through `php`. I have done this in the past but with `sftp` but not with `ftp`.

I want to achieve something like the following that I have done for `sftp`:

```
sftp -b commands.txt user@host
```

The `commands.txt` file contains the `ftp` commands to be run in the server (e.g `mget`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common Linux `ftp` does not have any option to provide a script file.

But you can use a [standard input redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Redirecting_standard_input_and_standard_output) instead:

```
ftp < commands.txt
```